# What is installing Python modules or packages?

Tags: python, module, installation, package

A Python module is just a `.py` source file. A Python package is simply a collection of modules.

So why do we need programs such as `pip` to 'install' Python modules? Why not just download the files, put them in our project's folder and `import` them?

What exactly does it mean to 'install' a module or a package? And what exactly does `pip` do?

Are things different on Windows and on Linux?

Comment: How would you download the files?

Comment: @SimeonVisser Do you mean that `pip` is a tool for downloading modules from a central repository along with dependencies (similarily to Maven for Java)?

Comment: *"Why not just download the files, put them in our project's folder and import them?"* - well you could give that a go and see how it works out! Then you have to go and find its dependencies yourself, and either explicitly `.<vcs>ignore` each dependency or fill your repo with code that isn't yours. And what about keeping those dependencies up-to-date?

Comment: Basically yes. `pip` is a tool for downloading files and putting them in the right location on your machine.

Comment: `pip` can do more than just that. It will execute a module's `setup.py`, which in some cases (e.g. `numpy`) may involve some actual compilation etc.

Comment: Well, I think that `pip` was designed for quick download a package and easy to install it. The _install_ means **copy all files to the PATH**. However, open the web browser, find the package or module, download it, unconpress it...or just one line command. Which do you prefer?

Answer (score 5):

> So why do we need programs such as pip to 'install' Python modules? Why not just download the files, put them in our project's folder and import them?

It's just meant to facilitate the installation of softwares without having to bundle all the dependencies nor ask the user to download the files.

You can type `pip install mysoftware` and that will also install the required dependencies. You can also upgrade a software easily.

> What exactly does it mean to 'install' a module or a package? And what exactly does pip do?

It will copy the files in a directory that is in your Python path. This way you will be able to import the package without having to copy the directory in your project.

Answer (score 0):

With your proposal, for each and every project you have to download the required modules as dependencies. You have to download them again and again and add them with your project which is not very suitable though some platform like node.us do it.

What pip do is to keep the modules you installed in /use/lib/python*/site-packages/ so clearly it is included in your Python's path. So, when you try to import a module or package it checks in site-package if it exists. If exists,then this code will be used with your project. If not, you will get an error.